# Prove that the sequence $cos(nx+a_n)$ can not tend to $0$ for all x on a set of positive measure E

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fourier-series

The following hint is given: "Show first that it can not tend to a non $0$ limit. Use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma".
Riemann Lebesgue Lemma says that if f is integrable, then $\int_{R} f(x)cos(nx) dx \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$ and same for the sine.

My attempt: Let $ f_n(x)= [cos(nx) cos(a_n) - sin(nx) sin(a_n)]1_E (x), then |f_n(x)|\leq 2 (1_E(x))$ and since the indicator is integrable on R, we have by dominated convergence theorem that if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ then $\int f_n(x) \to \int f(x).$ Now if $f_n(x)$ tends to a non $0$ limit, then $\int_R cos(a_n) 1_E(x) cos(nx) - \int_R sin(a_n) sin(nx) 1_E(x)dx \to c \neq 0$. But the problem is I don't see how this contradicts the lemma since $cos(a_n) 1_E(x)$ and $sin(a_n) 1_E(x)$  are not functions of x only, they depend on n as well.. Can anyone help me out with this?

Note: $a_n$ is a given sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\cos(nx + a_n) = \cos(nx) \cos(a_n) - \sin(nx) \sin(a_n)$.

For any set $E$ of finite  measure, 
$$ \int_E \cos(n x + a_n)\; dx = \cos(a_n) \int_{\mathbb R} 1_E(x) \cos(nx)\; dx 
- \sin(a_n) \int_{\mathbb R} 1_E(x) \sin(nx)\; dx$$
By Riemann-Lebesgue, $\int_{\mathbb R} 1_E(x) \cos(nx)\; dx$ and 
$\int_{\mathbb R} 1_E(x) \sin(nx)\; dx$ go to $0$, thus so does 
$\int_E \cos(nx + a_n)\; dx$.  But if $\cos(nx + a_n) \to c \ne 0$ on $E$, we'd have $\int_E \cos(nx + a_n)\; dx \to c\; m(E)$.  So this says you can't have a nonzero limit on any set of positive measure.

EDIT: For the second part, note that $\cos(2 n x + 2 a_n) =2 \cos^2(n x + a_n) - 1$.

Comment: Thanks,what if $cos(a_n)$ does not tend to a limit though? Then $\int cos(nx+a_n) dx$ would not tend to $0$ hence we would not have a contradiction?

Comment: You just use the fact $|\cos(a_n)| \le 1$ and $|\sin(a_n)| \le 1$.

Comment: True, thanks. I just saw your new hint on the second part, I will try it now.

Comment: By the way, may I ask how in your proof we are allowed to interchange limit and integral? Is it because cos(nx+an) on E is bounded by 1_E which is integrable?

Comment: Also, I've tried using your hint to do the 2nd part but I am getting stuck.. Assume $cos(nx+a_n) \to 0$, then $cos(2nx+2a_n) \to -1$ which implies $\int_E cos(2nx+2a_n) dx \to -m(E)<0.$ But $\int_E cos(2nx+2a_n) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_R cos(ny+2a_n) 1_E(\frac{y}{2}) dy $ (by substituting y=2x) $= \frac{1}{2} (cos(2a_n) \int_R cos(ny) 1_E(\frac{y}{2}) dy - sin(2a_n) \int_R sin(ny) 1_E(\frac{y}{2}) dy) \to 0$ which is a contradiction. But I have no clue whether I can use substitution in Lebesgue integrals... I believe I can't. Can you help clarify? Thanks

Comment: Let $y = 2x$.  We know $\cos(ny + 2a_n)$ can't go to $-1$ on a set of positive measure by part 1.

Comment: so the substitution rule works in lebesgue integration too?